# Reachability False Positive

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, reachability

I'm getting false positives with my Reachability code. I get the UIAlert "No Internet Connection", when the network is available but not activated. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
//Check for Internet
Reachability* wifiReach = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"] retain];
NetworkStatus netStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];
switch (netStatus)
{
    case NotReachable:
    {
        NSLog(@"Access Not Available");
        break;
    }

    case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        NSLog(@"Reachable WWAN");
        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
    {
        NSLog(@"Reachable WiFi");
        break;
    }
}

if (netStatus==NotReachable){
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Internet Required" message:@"There is no internet connection. Please connect and try again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}else{
    //Push Controller
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086816/reachability-on-iphone-app-with-a-false-positive-will-it-get-past-apple

Comment: Not exactly, The answer on the question you cite is to just not use reachability as much. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281232/reachability-sometimes-fails-even-when-we-do-have-an-internet-connection explains in more detail

Comment: @stevebay22 What makes you think that that isn't the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as the previous question.

Reachability sometimes only gives the correct answer after your app, or some previous app, has tried to connect and waited for data.  So you might as well just try to get data from your connection, as that may well give you a more correct answer more quickly than asking the Reachability API.  Maybe just let the user decide an activity indicator has been spinning long enough.